# How to add a bit at the start of BitSet buffer?

Tags: java, bitset

I am using a BitSet buffer where i have about 500 bits inside and i want to add about 10 bits at the start of the buffer, i mean at index 0 so the rest of the buffer should be shifted but I dont see a way to "add" a bit only write methods, so if i already have a bit there it will be replaced, no added. 
Is there any way to do this or i have to copy all to a temporary BitSet, add my 10 bits and then add my 500 bits ?

Thank you :)

PD: Sorry my bad English feel free of making corrections too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to insert bits at the front without copying.

Perhaps you could reverse the order of the bits in your `BitSet`? If you did, that would mean you're now appending bits to the end of the set, which *can* be done cheaply.

Alternatively, you could encapsulate a `Deque` of `BitSet`s. Then inserting bits at the front could be accomplished by inserting a new `BitSet` at the front of the `Deque`.

Comment: Thank you, there is no option no reverse the order of BitSet so i have to create a temporaly BitSet and Deque is not an option :)